# Is Einstein 1 Copilot available in Partner Developer Editon?

Tags: einstein, partner-communities

We have Einstein GPT in our ORG but Einstein Copilot enable option doesn't appear?

Comment: Does [this](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/einstein-copilot-basics/enable-customize-copilot?trail_id=build-ai-assistants-with-einstein-copilot) help?

Answer (score 0):

Einstein Copilot can be accessed by purchasing Einstein 1 editions or by adding it on to Enterprise or Unlimited Editions and this is available in beta globally for sales cloud and service cloud only.

Check more details on Einstein Copilot [here](https://investor.salesforce.com/press-releases/press-release-details/2024/Salesforces-Einstein-Copilot-is-Here-The-Conversational-AI-Assistant-for-CRM-that-Delivers-Trusted-AI-Responses-Grounded-with-Your-Company-Data/default.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Vinay for the insights

Answer (score 0):

Right now we don't have that option for Partner Developer Edition but we can do so by Partner learning camp.
For individual practice get a five day trail using:
https://mcp76yxhtx84crlrk45yhv6lcsby.pub.sfmc-content.com/aha3qbdjy5j